# Iterative deepening search selected bad moves

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm writing a Nine Men's Morris game and so far I have a Negascout search that works just fine. However, I would like to added iterative deepening, so I came up with this code:

```java
public Move GetBestMove(IBoard board, int depth)
{        
    //Search limits (ms
    this.maxTime = 9000; 

    //Set initial window
    int alpha = -INFINITY, beta = INFINITY;
    int val = 0;

    //The move that will be returned
    Move bestMove = null;      

    //Get list of moves for the current board 
    List<Move> moves = board.getMoves();

    //Get the time search has started
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    //Iterate through the depths
    for (curDepth = 1; ; )
    {
        maxDepth = curDepth;

        //Reset alpha
        alpha = -INFINITY;

        //Reset the best score position
        int bestPos = -1;

        //Loop through all the moves
        for (int i = 0, n = moves.size(); i < n; i++)
        {
            //Make the move
            board.make(moves.get(i), true);

            //Search deeper
            val = negascout(board, curDepth, alpha, beta, startTime);

            //Undo the move
            board.undo(moves.get(i));

            //Keep best move
            if (val > alpha)
            {
                bestMove = moves.get(i);
                bestPos = i;
            }

            //Score missed aspiration window
            if (val <= alpha || val >= beta)
            {
                alpha = -INFINITY;
                beta = INFINITY;

                //Go to next iteration
                continue;
            }

            //Set new aspiration window
            alpha = val - ASPIRATION_SIZE;
            if (alpha < -INFINITY)
                alpha = -INFINITY;

            beta = val + ASPIRATION_SIZE;
            if (beta > INFINITY)
                beta = INFINITY;
        }

        //Move the best move to the top of the list
        if (bestPos != -1)
        {
            moves.remove(bestPos);
            moves.add(0, bestMove);
        }

        //Time check
        double curTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e6;
        if (curTime >= maxTime ||
            val == board.getMaxScoreValue() ||
            val == -board.getMaxScoreValue())
            break;

        //Increment current depth
        curDepth++;
    }

    //Return the move
    return bestMove;
}
```

I also use an aspiration window. However, the search returns the worst possible move!! I think that the problem is with re-/setting the search window. Should the search window be moved to the outer loop?

Comment: If it returns always the worst move you should check your selection branch `if(val > alpha)` Shouldn't that be the other way arround?

Comment: No. val has improved over alpha so it's the current best move so far

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using negascout, your initial call should look like

```
val = -negascout(board, curDepth - 1, -beta, -alpha, startTime);
```

Your root call is the exact opposite compared to internal nodes, so that explains why it's returning the worst possible move.

Answer (score 0):

The [iterative deepening strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search#Algorithm):

```
for (depth = 1;; depth++) {
    val = AlphaBeta(depth, -INFINITY, INFINITY); // or negascout
    if (TimedOut())
        break;
}
```

looks different to the one you implemented with `GetBestMove`. The inner loop (iterating through the possible moves) should be part of `negascout`. Further it seems, that you only store the move ordering at first depth level (1-ply), but to make the iterative deepening search really fast, it needs a move ordering at every depth searched so far. Iterative deepening not only has the advantage to take time into account (finish after x seconds), but also has the advantage of generating a good move ordering. And the alphabeta or negascout algorithm benefits from a good move ordering (try this move first because in a previous search it was the best). A common way to get a move ordering implemented is the [transposition table](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Transposition+Table).

The documents [The Main Transposition Table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070809015843/www.seanet.com/~brucemo/topics/hashing.htm) and [Iterative Deepening](http://web.archive.org/web/20070809015849/http://www.seanet.com/~brucemo/topics/iterative.htm) from Bruce Moreland where very helpful to me and I hope that the links can help you too!